# Exporting Multiple Variable Inputs to CAD in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, export, model

I am trying to create a tool that clips (X) layers from an area, and creates a CAD file with the layers. I'm using inline substitutions to fill in the names for the layers, (X), which are then supposed to be exported as CAD files. When I run the tool the way it is shown, all of the clips are created and sent to the appropriate folder, but only one CAD file is created. I'm assuming the issue is within the naming of the CAD Output, where a CAD file is created with the %Input Features% substitution, then each different layer that is exported is just overwriting the last due to the same substitution name.

[image: Tool Diagram]